# How to use Faker plugin or another text plugin in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

The idea came to me to make snippets with ready-made fake data in VS Code. I use this plugin like this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=giancarlopro.faker-snippets#book, but it only allows you to create single data, but I want to create several of them at once.

For example, I would like to make a snippet:

SomeApp

```
<div> 
<span>Faker::App.name</span>
<span>Faker::App.author</span>
</div>
```

And use it like this

```
SomeApp*3
```

to get this

```
<div> 
<span>Google Chrome</span>
<span>Google</span>
</div>
<div> 
<span>Photoshop</span>
<span>Adobe</span>
</div>
<div> 
<span>Steam</span>
<span>Valve</span>
</div>
```

Or maybe it's an idea for the sake of an idea. Can you give me some advice?